# How to find a substring within a string of special characters with regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string

```
element : 1

Description
This is the description of item 1
___________________

element : 2

Description
This is the description of item 2
______________________
```

This is its code :

```
var string = "element : 1\n\nDescription\nThis is the description of item 1\n_________________\n\nelement : 2\n\nDescription\nThis is the description of item 2\n____________________________"
```

and I want to be able to extract the substring starting from `element : 1` to `element : 2` with regex (inclusively or exclusively it doesn't matter for now)

I used the following code but it still doesn't work :

```
var regexStr = /element : 1\s*\n(.*)element : 2/
var rx = new RegExp(regexStr, "i")

console.log(string.match(rx));  //null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use

```
^element(?:(?!^element)[\s\S])+
```

With the multiline modifier, see [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/jwHZK1/1/).

---

Broken down this says:

```
^element         # match element at the start of a line
(?:              
    (?!^element) # neg. lookahead, making sure there's no element at the start of the line
    [\s\S]       # ANY character, including newlines...
)+               # ...as often as possible
```

Comment: It works perfectly in the regex editor, but do you have any idea why doesn't it work here ? https://es6console.com/jb8g6b5d/

Comment: @YouMa: You need to add the `multiline` flag: `.../im` See https://es6console.com/jb8h1ner/

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, the `.` does not match *every* character. It matches any single character except line terminators: `\n`, `\r`, `\u2028` or `\u2029`.

You can us `[\s\S]` instead:

`/element : 1\s*\n([\s\S]*)element : 2/`

For reference, `\s` means any whitespace character and `\S` is the inverse of that. Thus `[\s\S]` is "any character that is a whitespace character or not a whitespace character"... thus "any character".